# Find all values of $a > 0$ for which $\int_a^b \frac{\ln x}{x + ab} dx \ge 0$, $\forall \hspace{.1cm} b > 0$.

Tags: calculus, integration

I have to find all values of $a > 0$ such that the following inequality is true:

$$\int_a^b \dfrac{\ln x}{x + ab} \ge 0 \hspace{3cm} \forall \hspace{.1cm} b > 0$$

I tried a weird integration by parts but got nowhere. My textbook claims that the correct answer is $\{ 1 \}$. So the only value of $a$ for which that inequality is true $\forall \hspace{.1cm} b > 0$ is $1$. How can I reach this answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for $b=1$ we have that
$$\int_a^1\frac{\ln{(x)}}{x+a}\mathrm{d}x\lt0\quad\forall a\ne1$$
due to the fact that for $0\lt a\lt1$ we have $\ln{(x)}/(x+a)\lt0$ for all $a\lt x\lt1$ and for $a\gt1$ we have $\ln{(x)}/(x+a)\gt0$ for all $1\lt x\lt a$. One can use a similar argument to prove that for $a=1$ we have
$$\int_1^b\frac{\ln{(x)}}{x+b}\mathrm{d}x\ge0\quad\forall b\gt0$$